# using find in subprocess.call() gives error while the command executes properly from command prompt

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, command-prompt

```
C:\Windows\System32> ffmpeg -i D:\devaraj\KPIX_test.ts -vf "blackframe" -an -f n
ull - 2>&1|find "Parsed" > D:\devaraj\info.txt
```

this works fine , writes the file info.txt

```
subprocess.call('ffmpeg' ,'-i', 'D:\devaraj\KPIX_test.ts' ,'-vf', '"blackframe"', 'D:\devaraj\KPIX_textfinal.mp3', '- 2>&1>','|','find', '"Parsed"', '>' ,'D:\devaraj\info.txt', 'shell=True')
```

gives an error buffer size must be integer

were as

```
subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i D:\devaraj\KPIX_test.ts -vf "blackframe" -an -f n
ull - 2>&1|find "Parsed" > D:\devaraj\info.txt', shell=True)
```

gives an error

'find' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

any help would be appreciated from d bottom of heart

Comment: you should not use `find` and redirect to a file when you can get process output directly from python and parse it. XY problem probably

Comment: also, don't forget raw prefix or some backslashes may be interpreted as special chars

Comment: @ Jean-François Fabre ,i tried executing this 
output = subprocess.check_output(["ffmpeg","-i",r"D:\devaraj\KPIX_test.ts",
         "-vf","blackframe","-an","-f","null"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in output.decode().splitlines():
   if "Parsed" in line:
       print(line.rstrip() ,but it gives an error as                                           File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 211, inin check_output
    raise ValueError('stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.')
ValueError: stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.

Comment: oh right! sorry, edited the answer. Be careful if you're using python 2. Don't call decode on the result.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre     but the error remains same :(

Comment: not possible: `stdout` argument has been removed.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre sorry , the new error is like this,   File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 219, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)

Answer (score 0):

you should use native python methods to get filtered `ffmpeg` output:

```
ffmpeg -i D:\devaraj\KPIX_test.ts -vf "blackframe" -an -f null - 2>&1|find "Parsed"
```

To do this, you'd normally require `check_output` but this particular example is known to provide the required info but exit with a non-zero return code (using `run` from Python 3.5 would work, though)

So I'll use `Popen` instead. It becomes (as list, without all redirections and filters), then read all output from process standard output:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg","-i",r"D:\devaraj\KPIX_test.ts",
         "-vf","blackframe","-an","-f","null"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = p.stdout.read()
```

You don't need `shell=True`, and it merges error & output streams in the `output` variable.

Now `output` contains the output of ffmpeg command. Let's decode it (to get a string) and split the lines, check if the string is in the lines:

```
for line in output.decode().splitlines():  # python 2: output.splitlines()
   if "Parsed" in line:
       print(line.rstrip())  # or store it in a file, string, whatever
```

for a process outputting a lot more text, it would be better to iterate on `p.stdout` instead of reading the full contents (less memory hungry, allows real-time echo to the console)